# With multiple app users but same Apple ID, how to subscribe with appAccountToken differently in StoreKit2?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store, storekit

I'm testing the below code for purchasing auto-renewable subscriptions **locally with StoreKit2 local configuration file**.

```swift
let userId = UUID()
let result = try await product.purchase(options: [.appAccountToken(userId)])

switch result {
    case .success(let verification):
        logger.debug("Verification to be checked: \(verification.debugDescription)")
        let transaction = try checkVerified(verification)
        logger.debug("Purchase success: \(transaction.debugDescription)")

        await updateCustomerProductStatus()
        await transaction.finish()

        return transaction
    case .userCancelled:
        logger.debug("Purchase cancelled by user.")
        return nil
    case .pending:
        logger.debug("Purchase pending.")
        return nil
    default:
        return nil
}
```

Purchasing the first time is success without problems.
However when calling the `try await product.purchase(options: [.appAccountToken(userId)])` again **with a different userId**, the below pops up.

[image: You're currently subscribed to this]

And the `transaction.debugDescription` shows the OLD user ID instead of the new one.

Since the userId has changed, I assume the purchase with the new userId as appAccountToken should work like new purchase?

Comment: No. IAP doesn't care about the appAccountToken. It is just for your convenience and to help with fraud checking. An AppleID can only have one active subscription from a given subscription product at a time.  It is up to you to decide what to do when a different user logs into your app. You can either remove the subscription benefit from the old user and transfer it to the new user in your backend, allow both users to have the subscription benefit or decline to activate the benefit for the new user.